# SuiteCRM 403 Error (Forbidden) when trying to save template

Tags: sugarcrm, http-status-code-403, plesk, mod-security, suitecrm

Usually i try to resolve issue by my self, but in this case i am lost ;-)

I had install suiteCRM 7.8.2 on my server (managed with plesk onyx)

Everything work great except one thing :

- When i am trying to save a pdf template or an email template, i get an 403 error (Fobidden acces)

Things i have already done :

- trying chmod 777 for all files and folders of suiteCRM => Not working
- Change permission in config.php => Not working
- Quick Repair  => Not working
- Delete cache folder => Not working
- hitting on my laptop => Not working ... grrr..

I have no access to more information, in browser console i can see that SuiteCRM trying to send POST request to index.php and index.php answer 403 error, nothing in log file in debug mode...

I don't have more ideas ....

Thank you.
Rémi.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't provide much facts to investigate your issue. Consider to POST relevant configuration files from SuiteDRM and possible corresponding errors from your logs ( "/var/www/vhosts/system/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/logs" ) for further investigations. "Guessing" is very time-consuming and may not at all solve your root cause of an issue.

Comment: Solved ! Thank you, i am beginner in server management, i didn't think to look the apache log :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :

I have look "/var/www/vhosts/system/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/logs"

> [Sun Apr 02 21:34:58.173943 2017] [:error] [pid 29185] [client 82.227.112.246] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "rx ((?:submit(?:\\+| )?(request)?(?:\\+| )?>+|<<(?:\\+| )remove|(?:sign ?in|log ?(?:in|out)|next|modifier|envoyer|add|continue|weiter|account|results|select)?(?:\\+| )?>+)$|^< ?\\??(?: |\\+)?xml|^> ?$)" against "ARGS:sample" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/tortix/modsec/50_plesk_basic_asl_rules.conf"] [line "308"] [id "350147"] [rev "143"] [msg "Protected by Atomicorp.com Basic Non-Realtime WAF Rules: Potentially Untrusted Web Content Detected"] [data ""] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "XXXXXXXX"] [uri "/SuiteCRM/index.php"] [unique_id "WOFSYtX2OSwAAHIBsoAAAAAF"]

It's modsecurity firewall !

So i have disabled the 350147 rules from modsecurity (https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/73383/ + Switching off Rules)

It's work !

Thanks to  UFHH01 , i love you ;-)